# How to generate MD5 hash for a file located in a Http Url?

Tags: c#, md5

I am writing a web crawler to search for files and download. My problem is I do not want to download the same files that are downloaded already to the local drive. I know it's possible to use the MD5 hash to compare but how can I do this on HTTP URL without downloading them to the local disk?

If this approach is wrong. Please advice on a better solution

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless the webserver has some sort of service that shares the MD5, then No.

Computing a file hash requires every byte in the file.  This is why changing a single byte changes the hash, to prevent getting modified files.

Answer (score 3):

To generate a hash you're going to need the data (ie, you'll need to download it somehow).

I would suggest that you investigate using the [`If-Modified-Since`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) HTTP header instead (or maybe [`ETag`/`If-None-Match`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag), if the particular server provides it).

Answer (score 0):

The only comparison you will be able to perform on a remote file is a size comparison. Unfortunately, this is probably not enough to determine that the contents are identical or not.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but PowerShell 5+ can help to get MD5 of remote Url file by auto downloading it as a stream of bytes, then computing MD5 in one step:

```
$wc = [System.Net.WebClient]::new()
$pkgurl = 'http://www.remoteurl/file.zip'
$FileHash = Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 -InputStream ($wc.OpenRead($pkgurl)) 
write-host $FileHash.Hash
```